# iOS Charts Cubic Graph Demo - Outside Labels Not working

Tags: ios-charts

In the demo project, `CubicLineChartViewController`

If you change

`yAxis.labelPosition = YAxisLabelPositionInsideChart;`

to

`yAxis.labelPosition = YAxisLabelPositionOutsideChart;`

The labels don't show. I have compared notes with the other demos but I can't see what is different that makes this not work.

[image: no labels]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am facing same issue and by changing view port you can find your label is there and visible now.

Please remove below line from Demo app

it will work as expected.

```
[_chartView setViewPortOffsetsWithLeft:0.f top:20.f right:0.f bottom:0.f];
```

some how due to this line its moved chart view port so its hiding your labels from charts.

Hope this will helps to get your Yaxis label back.